# Flash Player Audio Channels

Tags: google-chrome, audio, flash-player

The problem came with the latest update (11.3.300), now whenever I'm watching YouTube or another website that uses flash it's sending audio out of all my speakers. I have 5.1 surround sound, before it would only use the 2 channels (left and right) if the audio track was stereo.

Now it sounds strange because it's splitting the audio into the maximum number of channels I have. None of the settings on my sound card / speaker were touched.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Or do I wait for an update?

PS. I'm using the latest Chrome Beta 21.0.1180.60 however this also happens in IE with the latest flash player installed.

As far as I know this problem is in Firefox too.  The problem is not with the video itself, because when I grab the mp4/flv file to disk and play it in standard video player it works just fine (stereo).

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that [Adobe is not willing to fix this](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3289908), I developed a workaround: [StopBraindeadSurround](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4SHVPm2DfK5OHo3Z29SSWJycWc/edit?usp=sharing). See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/567036/8695) for details.